# A hadoop job complete without map and reduce on a Hadoop Cluster( one namenode ,12 datanode)

Tags: java, hadoop, jobs

I wrote a hadoop program and ran it on a single machine,it worked good.
But it encountered below problems (job didn't start and finished immediately after map start) when I migrated it to a cluster (one namenode, 12 datanode)

command ran on the terminal:

> hadoop jar VOConeSearch.jar input output 142.82 -3.32 1

(here input is a directory in hdfs for input,output is the hdfs directory program write to,there is no output directory in hdfs before execution,and  142.82 ,-3.32 ,1 are three extra parameters)

**cluster info**
when I ran the program,input directory contains 167537 files

```
11/06/11 09:33:49 INFO security.Groups: Group mapping impl=org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping; cacheTimeout=300000
11/06/11 09:33:50 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.task.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.attempt.id
11/06/11 09:33:50 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
11/06/11 09:33:57 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 167537
11/06/11 09:37:36 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
11/06/11 09:37:36 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
11/06/11 09:37:36 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: adding the following namenodes' delegation tokens:null
11/06/11 09:37:36 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_201106081653_0011
11/06/11 09:37:37 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
11/06/11 09:37:37 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job complete: job_201106081653_0011
11/06/11 09:37:37 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 4
    Job Counters 
        Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
        SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=0
        SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=0
```

It seems that the job complete in 0 seconds,but there is no output directory in hdfs. Same program ran on a single machine(namenode,datanode exist on the same machine) but there is only one file in the (hdfs) input directory.

single node info with one file in input directory

```
11/06/11 10:07:54 INFO security.Groups: Group mapping
impl=org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping; cacheTimeout=300000
11/06/11 10:07:54 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.task.id is deprecated. Instead, use
mapreduce.task.attempt.id
11/06/11 10:07:54 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing
the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
11/06/11 10:07:54 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
11/06/11 10:07:54 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead,
use mapreduce.job.maps
11/06/11 10:07:54 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
11/06/11 10:07:55 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: adding the following namenodes'
delegation tokens:null
11/06/11 10:07:55 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_201106111004_0001
11/06/11 10:07:56 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
11/06/11 10:08:11 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
11/06/11 10:08:17 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
11/06/11 10:08:19 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job complete: job_201106111004_0001
11/06/11 10:08:19 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 33
    FileInputFormatCounters
        BYTES_READ=66580278
    FileSystemCounters
        FILE_BYTES_READ=6562
        FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=13156
        HDFS_BYTES_READ=66580392
        HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN=6941
    Shuffle Errors
        BAD_ID=0
        CONNECTION=0
        IO_ERROR=0
        WRONG_LENGTH=0
        WRONG_MAP=0
        WRONG_REDUCE=0
    Job Counters 
        Data-local map tasks=1
        Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
        SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=8744
        SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=3189
        Launched map tasks=1
        Launched reduce tasks=1
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Combine input records=0
        Combine output records=0
        Failed Shuffles=0
        GC time elapsed (ms)=867
        Map input records=118249
        Map output bytes=6512
        Map output records=11
        Merged Map outputs=1
        Reduce input groups=1
        Reduce input records=11
        Reduce output records=11
        Reduce shuffle bytes=6562
        Shuffled Maps =1
        Spilled Records=22
        SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=114
```

part of hadoop program

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    if(args.length != 5)
    {
        System.out.println("Usage : HadoopTest <input path> <output path> <ra> <dec> <sr>");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    
    
    Job job = new Job();
    
    job.setJarByClass(HadoopTest.class);
    Configuration conf = job.getConfiguration();
    
    if(!isDouble(args[2])||!isDouble(args[3])||!isDouble(args[4]))
    {
        System.out.println("RA DEC SR should be real number");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    
    DefaultStringifier.store(conf, new DoubleWritable(Double.parseDouble(args[2])), "ra");
    DefaultStringifier.store(conf, new DoubleWritable(Double.parseDouble(args[3])), "dec");
    DefaultStringifier.store(conf, new DoubleWritable(Double.parseDouble(args[4])), "sr");
    
    
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job,new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    
    job.setMapperClass(ConeSearchMap.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(ScircleWritableComparable.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    
    job.setReducerClass(ConeSearchReduce.class);
    
    job.setOutputKeyClass(ScircleWritableComparable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)? 0 : 1);
}
```

Comment: When you look at your job on the web interface, do you see any map failures or anything?

Comment: how should we access your home files?

Comment: I saw the web interface and found that the job revealed map 100% and reduce 100% in retired job,but the stated is FAILED.In the detailed page all columns are 0(Setup,Map,Reduce,Cleanup).After I clicked 'Analyse This Job',it echoed 'No Analysis available as job did not finish'. But in fact the job completed.

Comment: When you click on the job, you should see a column in the first table that says "Failed/Killed Task Attempts". If you see any failed attempts (the numbers before the /'s...) click on the number, tell us whether it's a map or reduce task, and paste the error message into your question.

Comment: Actually, do you see *any* failed tasks, or does the job fail before it starts any tasks?

Comment: The job failed before starting any tasks. There were no tasks (suc,fail or any ohter).

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to set the input format in your job object:

```
   SequenceFileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, in);
   SequenceFileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);
   job.setInputFormatClass(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);
   job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
```

So you should replace it with a concrete subclass of FileInputFormat, like `TextFileInputFormat` or `SequenceFileInputFormat`.

It's the same with your output.

Comment: Thank you very much.TextInputFormat works,but SequenceFileInputFormat didn't work. Hadoop said the file in hdfs isn't sequence file.

Comment: I ran my program using TextInputFormat with smaller files(7897 files),And the job ran well,however the job encountered the same problem (question above) when it ran with bigger files (167537 files).So I thought maybe it have some other problems.

Comment: What files do you want? Can I send to your email?

Comment: I don't want any files, @ajduff574 wanted something. I don't know why it does not work with so many files. Why don't you split the jobs then?

Comment: I thought about that,but starting a new job costs a lot of time. I used hadoop for cutting down the time of searching large scale data. Breaking down the job will enlarge the time. But maybe I have to do that. Maybe hadoop can't handle too much files once a time. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm so sorry :( Maybe some other can help you!

Comment: Don't. You help me a lot. At least TextInputFormat tackle multi files problem. FileInputFormat can't handle multi files. Thank you sincerely.